# Class Based Click Event Irresponsive after 10 Rows - Datatables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

I have a Table as such:

```
<?php 
    foreach($cars->result() as $car){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td id="'.$car->car_id.'_id">'.$car->car_id.'</td>';
    echo '<td id="'.$car->car_id.'_nm">'.$car->car_name.'</td>';
    echo '<td id="'.$car->car_id.'_ph">'.$car->rate_per_hr.'</td>';
    echo '<td id="'.$car->car_id.'_pk">'.$car->rate_per_km.'</td>';
    echo '<td id="'.$car->car_id.'_mh">'.$car->min_hrs.'</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="#" id="ed_'.$car->car_id.'" class="car_edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="#" id="de_'.$car->car_id.'" class="car_delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?>
```

I am using DataTables to display the datagrid.

Now, I have an Edit Button for each row which bears the same class but seperate IDs as the code above demonstrates. Based on the click on the class I am extracting the ID and then doing some ajax operations.

Code Edited for simplicity

```
 $('.car_edit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var id= $(this).attr('id');
  var len = id.length;
  var row_id = id.substr(3 , len);
  console.log(row_id);
});
```

Now, this is working perfectly fine for the first 10 rows (Default Display of the DataTables) after which the click event is not triggered.

I am bending my mind over this. Please help me point out my mistake.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jquery `on()`:

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on('click','.car_edit',function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       var id= $(this).attr('id');
       var len = id.length;
       var row_id = id.substr(3 , len);
       console.log(row_id);
   });
});
```

According to docs: `Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements` https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks a lot. I shall go through the documentation very closely.